# Usb wireless adapter causing DPC spikes

Tags: wireless-networking, interrupts, process-explorer, perfmon, dpc

Bought 2 new TP-LINK WN722N USB wirless adapters as they were the highest rated on Newegg and were a great price. Both of them cause abnormally high DPC & Interrupt usage in Process Explorer and perfmon. This appears both on x86 and x64 machines. I'm using the latest drivers from the TP-LINK website and even downloaded the latest driver from the Atheros website for this chipset. No dice in resolving the issue. Removing the adapter ends spikes so it is to blame.

Is this typical? Should I be concerned? Does anybody here own this adapter and notice similar behavior? I expected better from such a highly rated product.

[image: Proces Explorer screenshot]